# CSS: Height = Width (another case)

Tags: css

I try to make via css the same (a priori unknow) Width and Height.

There are multiple ways of doing it ([1](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp), [2](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html)) but any didn't work in my case:

```css
.cont{height: 150px; width: 300px; background: lightgray;} /*size is unknow*/
.cont>div:nth-child(odd){background:pink;}
.cont>div:nth-child(even){background:green;}
.bordered{border:1px solid red;}

.square{
 position: relative;
 width: auto;  /* desired width */
}
.square:before{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
.square>div{
 position:  absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="col-xs-4">a
    <div class="square"><div class="bordered"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/100">red bordered SQUARE auto width does not work, content size is unknow!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">b
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">c
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preconditions**:

- The parents of the square or their dimensions are unknown.
- The content of the square or its dimensions are unknown(I put an image with some text inside just to give to the container some heterogeneous content).
- So I can't control any of these(parents or children), nor modify its properties.
- The only thing I can control is the **`.square`** element or/and its immediate(and unique) child.

**Question**: How to achieve having a CSS *square*(red bordered) in that case, without having to specify the width in pixels (keep it "auto" by content)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Your code is definitely not a complete, minimal, example of the problem you are facing.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on this.)

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard I specified the question in the edit

Answer (score 0):

I've called on the img inside of the squared class to match the dimensions of it's container.  Just two adjustments, one with the css for the img element:

```
    .square img{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
}
```

and I adjusted the height of the lorempixel image you're requesting.

```
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/125"></div>
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyd9z7xL/)

Comment: The square's content is unknown. I can't control it. Also all the possible parents of the square are unknown... The example I gave is just to be able to visualize a case of infinite combinations....

Answer (score 0):

try making the class of the `<img>` tag bordered:

```css
.cont{height: 300px; width: 500px; background: lightgray;}
.cont>div:nth-child(odd){background:pink;}
.cont>div:nth-child(even){background:green;}
.bordered{border:1px solid red;}

.square{
 position: relative;
 width: auto;  /* desired width */
}
.square:before{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
.square>div{
 position:  absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="col-xs-4">a
    <div class="square"><div><img class="bordered" src="http://lorempixel.com/125/100"></div></div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">b
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">c
  </div>
</div>
```

I also changed the size of the `.cont` div so the image will fit.

Comment: As the container width and heights are unknow(I set it just to set something). So modifying them does not change the problem...

Comment: The size change was just so it looks nicer, the class change is what i'm focusing my answer on.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I need a div that can contain various content to be a square... I put the image inside just to demonstrate different type of content that my square could have inside, so instead of the image there could be another stuff... the class I need to make as square is the content of the .square, not a specific image or other tag...